# MySql overlapping dates can't get it right

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a query with overlapping dates.
My tabel look like this'

```
Agenda ID   DateStart               DateEnd
-------------------------------------------------------
1           2012-04-02 08:00:00     2012-04-02 11:30:00
2           2012-04-02 10:00:00     2012-04-02 13:00:00
3           2012-04-02 12:00:00     2012-04-02 15:00:00
```

This data is for planning activities. You can't plan a activity if the time overlaps.
In this case all the times overlap. But he compares it to the one you planned earlier.
Say I planned ID 1, so I can't plan ID 2, But I can plan ID 3.

How Can I write A query with php to select the items that overlap.
Thank you very much

```
SELECT
   agenda.DateStart,
   agenda.DateEnd,
   agenda.AgendaID
FROM
   AGENDA
WHERE
   ????
   AND
   ????
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select a.DateStart, a.DateEnd, a.AgendaId, b.DateStart, b.DateEnd, b.AgendaId
from agenda a, agenda b
where 
a.AgendaId <> b.AgendaId
and b.DateStart>= a.DateStart and
b.DateStart<= a.DateEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_Orders = "SELECT * FROM AGENDA WHERE fldTime between  DateStart  and DateENd ";
```

You can check with the **MYSQL** `BETWEEN` keyword.